# GROUP BY in Group Contact in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite

I would like to add order by in GROUP_CONCAT

The Request

```
        SELECT LRU.InstanceDesc as lru , 
GROUP_CONCAT((DataSourceGroup.DataSourceGroupID||'~'||TYPE||'~'||DataSource.`NDOID`||'~'||DataSource.Name ),'@') as data_souce , 

        FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TYPE,DataSourceGroupID,EQID,LRUID,DataFieldID FROM 
EquationDataPresort) EquationDataPresort    

        LEFT OUTER JOIN DataSource ON (DataSourceGroup.DataSourceID = DataSource.DataSourceID)  

        WHERE LRU.LRUID = '406' AND EquationDataPresort.`DataSourceGroupID` > -1 AND 
EquationDataPresort.EQID = '-1' GROUP BY LRU.InstanceDesc
```

I would like to ORDER BY DataSource.Name . How i can do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) says:

> The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.

You can hope that the order is kept if you take the values from a subquery whose rows already have the correct order:

```
SELECT lru,
       GROUP_CONCAT(data_source, '@') AS data_source
FROM (SELECT LRU.InstanceDesc AS lru,
             DataSourceGroup.DataSourceGroupID||'~'||... AS data_source
      FROM ...
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
      WHERE ...
      ORDER BY 1, 2)
GROUP BY lru
```